# How to include MS Access 2007 Runtime as a prerequisite to msi

Tags: ms-access, runtime

I am making a windows application that uses MS Access 2007 as backend database. To install this application on other machines, the machine need to have MS Access 2007 or MS Access Runtime 2007. As MS Access Runtime 2007 is redistributable I decided to bundle it in my MSI.

Problem is that in Visual Studio 2008, in prerequisite options I can not find MS Access Runtime 2007 as an option, rather I have Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies. So I am not sure how to proceed.

Someone's feedback with previous experience on the same will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using an ACCDB to store data then you don't need Access 2007 or the Access 2007 run time.  All you need is the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734) or [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)

However I can't answer the rest of your question.